# I need to print out all of the words in the file that begin with an uppercase character

Tags: c

i need to access a file and from that file i need to print out all the words that starts with a capital letter and also how many times the words have occurred. for example in the file there is a text "the Program should Display Files and also Files"
now the output should be:

Text

Program

Display

Files(2)//This word is written two times

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Jf4.png)

Comment: Please do not include code as an image. The relevant code, sufficiently complete to understand and reproduce the issue, should be included in the question.

Comment: Please post code as text, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: @dbush what is wrong with posting pictures or link ? all it takes is single click.

Comment: @KBlr if the code would be text, I would have copy/paste it to the answer, fix the bug and post it. I will not type the whole code from the picture.

Comment: @KBlr Pictures are bad because we can't copy and paste the code to run it, and links are bad because they could break in the future.

Comment: @KBlr furthermore there is no chance anyone might find this question when searching for any text present in the picture. This makes the question useless for any future reader. And external resources might also expire at some time.

Answer (score 1):

`while (!feof(..))` is normally not a good idea, instead write

```
while (fgets(readLine,sizeof(readLine), fpointer) != NULL)
{
}
```

it seems ptr is superfluous in this context, if you want to check for words in the line you should move it forward in the line?

alt. use instead the runtime function strtok:

```
for (ptr = strtok(readLine, " "); ptr != NULL; ptr = strtok(NULL, " ")
{
   // now ptr will point to each word in the line, then you just check
   // if the first character is upper case.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework assignment, so I am not going to put the code here. I can give you the steps to take to have a general idea:

- [Open and read the file](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output)
- Use something like [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to split the lines into words
- Loop over the words and check the first character (remember that a word is an array of chars. You can check if it's in range of 60 - 95 as based on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).
- To count words you can create a hashmap in which you store the word with a count as value e.g. `{word1: 1, word2: 2}`
- In the end you go over all the keys in the hashmap and print the key + count.